# Tmux copy mode Home and End keys

Tags: tmux

I've configured vim copy mode in tmux 2.5 with

```
setw -g mode-keys vi
```

But now to go to the start of the line I have to use 0 and to go to the end of the line I have to use $. How do I remap them to the Home and End keys?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the config:

```
bind -T copy-mode-vi 'Home' send -X start-of-line
bind -T copy-mode-vi 'End'  send -X end-of-line
```

or

```
bind -T copy-mode-vi 'Home' send 0
bind -T copy-mode-vi 'End'  send $
```

Just don't forget the single quotes otherwise it will not work. If you don't use vi-mode then simply drop the `-vi`.

Reference: `man tmux`, search for "in copy mode" in the [section WINDOWS AND PANES](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html#WINDOWS_AND_PANES) and afterwards read the "send-keys" command.