# Scroll up and down in tmux using u and f

Tags: tmux

I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> and <kbd>PageUp</kbd> to enter copy mode and scroll one page up in `tmux`. After entering `copy-mode`, I can use <kbd>PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>PageDown</kbd> to scroll up and down.

However, I want to use the <kbd>u</kbd> and <kbd>f</kbd> keys for this purpose instead of the <kbd>PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>PageDown</kbd> keys so that I can avoid having to take my hand off the home row.

What settings can I do to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tmux copy mode Home and End keys](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396005/tmux-copy-mode-home-and-end-keys)

Comment: It does give me the key idea of how to remap the keys, but does not answer the question fully. There is an additional keybinding required in normal mode for this question. I have noted this in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the hint from one of the comments and was able to get the desired functionality by adding the following lines to my `tmux.conf`

`u` and `f` in copy-mode are mapped to `PageUp` and `PageDown`

```
bind -T copy-mode u send -X page-up
bind -T copy-mode f send -X page-down
```

`u` in normal mode enters copy mode and scrolls up by one page

```
bind u copy-mode -u
```